# Update key column type in ClickHouse

Tags: clickhouse

I try to update column type from DateTime(TZ) to DateTime, but it is key column and couldn't be changed. Drop/create table doesn't have any result - looks like metadata stored in ZK.
Can I change table structure (I can drop/create table) without changing ZK records? Or it is required to remove meta from ZK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to drop a table at all replicas. If  you lost a replica and did notdrop  their table you need to clean ZK manually.

Or you can just use another ZK path. Table name does matter.

Comment: yes, it works, instead of DROP <table> you should use just DROP <yable> ON CLUSTER <cluster>, many thanks!